# Отправка данных на сервер с опустевшей формой

Tags: php, html

На странице изначально есть форма (метод POST) с кнопкой "Проверить", которая обрабатывается в этом же файле и выводит введенный текст в генерирующуюся таблицу.
Одновременно с появлением заполненной таблицы и новой кнопкой "Добавить", форма пустеет и отправить данные через "Добавить" не получается, а хотелось бы.

Вопрос: как отправить данные из переменных (в которых сохранилась заполненная форма) с помощью новой кнопки (например, моей "Добавить")?

```
<form action = "" method = "post">
    <input required name = "concert_name" type = "text">
    <input name = "new_concert_check" type = "submit" value = "Проверить">
</form>

<? php
    if(isset($_POST["new_concert_check"]) && !empty($_POST["new_concert_check"])) {
        $new_concert_name = $_POST["concert_name"];

         echo '<table><tr><th>'.$new_concert_name.'</th></tr></table>';

         echo '<p><input name = "add_concert" type = "submit value = "Добавить"></p>'; 

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action = "" method = "post">
    <input required name = "concert_name" type = "text" value="<?=(isset($_POST["concert_name"]) ? $_POST["concert_name"] : '')?>" >
    <input name = "new_concert_check" type = "submit" value = "Проверить">
</form>
<? php
    if(isset($_POST["new_concert_check"]) && !empty($_POST["new_concert_check"])) {
        $new_concert_name = $_POST["concert_name"];

         echo '<table><tr><th>'.$new_concert_name.'</th></tr></table>';             
         echo '<p><input name = "add_concert" type = "submit value = "Добавить"></p>'; 

    }
?>
```

Просто как пример как именно это сделать, но нужна проверка на то что именно было передано.

Или вариант 2.

```
         echo '<table><tr><th>'.$new_concert_name.'</th></tr></table>';             
         echo '<p><input name = "add_name" hidden value = "'.$new_concert_name.'"></p>'; 
         echo '<p><input name = "add_concert" type = "submit value = "Добавить"></p>';
```

p.s. Такие проверки лучше делать с помощью Ajax

Comment: Спасибо, но 1) первый метод не сохраняет то, что было введено в форму в кавычках и 2) в форме ещё есть radio, а там value занят информацией, которая нужна при проверке

Comment: 1) в первом примере нет фильтрации(а она нужна) и об этом написано.
2а) В примере нет Radio, там либо checked у существующего радио ставится(если пример 1 использовать) 
2б) если пример 2 использовать то просто еще один input hidden заводите с нужным значением

Comment: Столько костылей написал - ни на что не ругается, но всё равно данные не отправляются в БД. Внутри формы после кнопки "Проверить" открыл php-код (подключение к БД, и проверка нажатия на "Проверить", если срабатывает - внутри формы генерируется кнопка "Добавить", которая и отправляет переменные в БД). После закрываю форму и открываю ещё php-код, который проверяет нажатие на "Проверить" и запускает генерацию таблицы и всё закрываю. Всё работает: кнопка "Добавить" появляется внутри форма, а таблица генерируется вне, НО не отправляется, а я всё перепробовал.

Comment: Вы слишком перемудрили архитектуру, не нужно данные проверять 2 раза. Если вы хотите заранее предупредить пользователя что такие данные "невозможны"\"заняты"\"что то еще" - не делайте из этого культ, это делается Ajax запросом, а не повторной валидацией.
Опишите точно задачу, и для чего именно реализована двойная отправка данных.

Comment: После вноса данных в форму надо нажать "Проверить", генерируется новая кнопка "Добавить"  и таблица с одной строкой из данных формы (ещё не внесенных в БД), и две строки таблицы подгружается из БД. После того, как пользователь проверил правильность заполнения, он нажимает кнопку "Добавить", и данные только тогда заносятся в БД.

Comment: Так не делается =) 1 вариант после кнопки проверить, если все верно данные сразу заносятся в БД, с пометкой "временные данные" и пользователю выводится предложение подтвердить данные, если он их подтверждает - снимается отметка "временности", данные становятся постоянными.
2 вариант - все проверки ведутся через Ajax запросы без отправки всей формы..
То что вы пытаетесь сделать - идеологически неверно, вам нужно будет оба раза перепроверять данные, ибо пользователь может их изменить когда у него уже будет доступна кнопка подтверждения, p.s. оба варианта используются для разного результата.

Comment: Ох, много времени зря потратил... Большое спасибо за помощь, буду пробовать временными делать!

Comment: Не забудьте ограничить время на снятие пометки "временные" и записывать время занесения данных, или например сразу вносить время в которое данные удалятся.... т.е. предусмотреть случай когда пользователь просто проигнорировал кнопку подтвердить\отменить

Comment: Надо было маму слушаться и идти на гуманитарную специальность, спасибо за предупреждение